# What is the recommended oracle 19.16 ojdbc version

Tags: oracle, ojdbc

I am using Oracle 19.16RU and JDK 17. Can you recommend which version of ojdbc I should use?

I'm trying ojdbc11 and 23.x.x.x version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 23.3 release is a *developer* release that can be used to test the new features of the 23c database, but should not be used in production as one-off patches won't be delivered in case of bugs. The 23.4 release will be the first *production* release with full support from Oracle.

Since you're using a 19c database you can also use the 19c JDBC driver. The latest Release Update is 19.21 that can be downloaded [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html).

Answer (score 1):

23.3.x.x is not for production use. You should wait for next release i.e. 23.4.x.x. I think you can use ojdbc jar from latest 19.x RU or 21.x RU.